# jqGrid custom pager search button

Tags: jqgrid

We have our custom button that is ASP.NET custom server control. We use it on all our pages for action buttons (< NS:OurButton ID='btn' runat="server" Text="Search"/ >).

Now we want to use that button to open our custom search form to filter the records in jqGrid.
Our business requirement that the search button must be a part of jqGrid pager.

How I can do it? I tried to search google and wiki help for jqGrid, but didn't found any way how to add that custom search button to the jqGrid pager.

If it's matters, the button rendered to the client in that markup:

```
<div id="btn" class="OurCustomButton">
    <div class="LeftSide"></div>
    <div class="ButtonContent">Search</div>
    <div class="RightSide"></div>
</div>
```

Or maybe it's possible to create totally my own custom pager, with my own design and buttons and then to tell the jqGrid to use it's controls as triggers or to trigger events on my own with correct parameters?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is to use jQuery's [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)(or [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)) and have the html for your button inserted on the document.ready() event.

The code could be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
$('<div class="ButtonContent">Search</div>').insertBefore('.RightSide');
});
```